# I am trying to read a excel using linqToexcel. But i am not able to read when the headers are not in the first row.

Tags: c#, linq-to-excel

LinqToexcel works only when the headers are in the first row.
How can i read by header names instead of first row .
Can any one help ?

Comment: What happens when the headers are not in the first row?  does it throw a `DoesNotWorkException`?

Answer (score 0):

**Query Column Names**

The GetColumnNames() method can be used to retrieve the list of column names in a worksheet.

```
var excel = new ExcelQueryFactory("excelFileName");
var columnNames = excel.GetColumnNames("worksheetName");
```

**Property to column mapping**

Column names from the worksheet can be mapped to specific property names on the class by using the AddMapping() method. The property name can be passed in as a string or a compile time safe expression.

```
var excel = new ExcelQueryFactory("excelFileName");
excel.AddMapping<Company>(x => x.State, "Providence"); //maps the "State" property to the "Providence" column
excel.AddMapping("Employees", "Employee Count");       //maps the "Employees" property to the "Employee Count" column

var indianaCompanies = from c in excel.Worksheet<Company>()
                       where c.State == "IN" && c.Employees > 500
                       select c;
```

Column names can alternately be mapped using the ExcelColumn attribute on properties of the class.

```
public class Company
{
    [ExcelColumn("Company Title")] //maps the "Name" property to the "Company Title" column
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [ExcelColumn("Providence")] //maps the "State" property to the "Providence" column
    public string State { get; set; }

    [ExcelColumn("Employee Count")] //maps the "Employees" property to the "Employee Count" column
    public string Employees { get; set; }
}
```